# Mule ESB 3.5 - Error create ws client

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, mule

I've got a problem with a ws client in a mule flow.
I generated the classes from a wsdl with cxf.
When I start the mule server, I get an exception in class:
org.mule.module.cxf.builder.AbstractOutboundMessageProcessorBuilder

```
    try
    {
        client = createClient();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new DefaultMuleException(e);
    }
```

The exception is org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: Unable to locate imported document at 'http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1/swaref.xsd', relative to 'schema5.xsd'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share the WSDL file you are using? There were some bugs regarding imported/included schemas.

Comment: Hmmm ... I don't think it's a problem due to wsdl. We are changing mule version from 3.2 to 3.5, The same flow works properly under mule 3.2, but not with mule 3.5 ...